# Failed to stop background service

Tags: java, android, service

I am developing an application where it records the video in the background, But while recording is in progress and when I stop the recording by pressing the stop button it will throw an error  saying **java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to stop service**

**Following is my service class code:-**

```
@Override
    public void onCreate() {
        // Start foreground service to avoid unexpected kill

        Notification notification = new Notification.Builder(this)
                .setContentTitle("Background Video Recorder")
                .setContentText("Background video recording started...")
                .setSmallIcon(R.mipmap.ic_launcher)
                .build();
        startForeground(1234, notification);
        // Create new SurfaceView, set its size to 1x1, move it to the top left corner and set this service as a callback


        windowManager = (WindowManager) this.getSystemService(Context.WINDOW_SERVICE);
        surfaceView = new SurfaceView(this);

        WindowManager.LayoutParams layoutParams = new WindowManager.LayoutParams(1, 1,
                WindowManager.LayoutParams.TYPE_SYSTEM_OVERLAY,
                WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_WATCH_OUTSIDE_TOUCH,
                PixelFormat.TRANSLUCENT
        );

        layoutParams.gravity = Gravity.LEFT | Gravity.TOP;
        windowManager.addView(surfaceView, layoutParams);
        surfaceView.getHolder().addCallback(this);

        pref= getApplicationContext().getSharedPreferences("Recorder",0);
        editor = pref.edit();
    }

    // Method called right after Surface created (initializing and starting MediaRecorder)
    @Override
    public void surfaceCreated(SurfaceHolder surfaceHolder) {
        camera = Camera.open();
        mediaRecorder = new MediaRecorder();
        camera.unlock();
        mediaRecorder.setPreviewDisplay(surfaceHolder.getSurface());
        mediaRecorder.setCamera(camera);
        mediaRecorder.setAudioSource(MediaRecorder.AudioSource.CAMCORDER);
        mediaRecorder.setVideoSource(MediaRecorder.VideoSource.CAMERA);
        mediaRecorder.setProfile(CamcorderProfile.get(CamcorderProfile.QUALITY_HIGH));
        String file = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory()+"/:"+DateFormat.format("yyyy-MM-dd_kk-mm-ss", new Date().getTime())+".mp4";
        mediaRecorder.setOutputFile(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory()+"/:"+DateFormat.format("yyyy-MM-dd_kk-mm-ss", new Date().getTime())+".mp4");

        editor.putString("file_path",file);
        editor.commit();

        try {
            mediaRecorder.prepare();
            mediaRecorder.start();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
@Override
    public void onDestroy() {
        mediaRecorder.stop();
        mediaRecorder.reset();
        mediaRecorder.release();
        camera.lock();
        camera.release();
        windowManager.removeView(surfaceView);
       }
```

**Code for stop button:-**

```
public void stopVideo(View view){
        Toast.makeText(this, "Video Recording stopped", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        Intent intent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, CameraService.class);
        stopService(intent);
        Intent i  = new Intent(this, MainActivity.class);
        startActivity(i);
    }
```

What is going wrong with it?

Comment: Can you please share the code what you do on stop button?

Comment: I have updated the code, please see it @AndyDeveloper

Comment: please show full exception stacktrace

Comment: Try to add this in onDestroy() if(mediaRecorder != null) {
mediaRecorder.stop();
mediaRecorder.release();
} if(camera != null) {
camera.release();
camera = null
}

Comment: Firstly, in stopVideo method definition you pass the 'View view' parameter which is never used. Secondly, you should show us where do you call this method.